# Feedback on PCB-layout wanted

Tags: pcb-design, spi, battery-operated, layout, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm currently making a weather station as a personal project. It will consist of one BLE peripheral and one BLE central. I will fabricate both as one PCB, and panelize them with a vcut.
As mentioned earlier, this is a personal project, so I would love to get some feedback on the layout so I can improve the design, and myself as a designer.

Some things worth mentioning:

- 2-layer design
- Uses Renesas DA14531mod BLE-modules
- Battery powered (3V0)
- Will display data on e-paper display through SPI.

Here is the schematic:
[image]

Here is the top layer:
[image]

And here is the bottom layer:
[image]

As I'm using the same ground for both PCBs in the schematic, there is a netline visible in the layout (over the vcut).

Comment: Possibly a personal preference and doesn't have any actual impact on performance, but I very much prefer schematics to have lines connecting parts together. Off-page connections should only be used for well, off-page connections ie. connecting signals to another schematics page. Also, when using off-page connectors you should use a symbol for that (typically an arrow or such), not just a net label.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny This is a good point and something I will take into consideration. The readability of the schematic would be improved. 
Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't net labels used for connections within the same sheet, and net ports used for connections between sheets? At least according to this article: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-circuit-connectivity-schematics?version=18.1 (See the section about flat design)

Comment: Lines win every time for me. Boxed-up miniature circuit sections don't work for me. They may work for some folk but, for EE pros, they are just another thing to mess up circuit flow.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I believe the general consensus among professionals is to connect everything located on the same schematic page with lines, but keep different functionality blocks on different pages. Like for example page 1: power, page 2: BLE module, page 3: sensors, page 4: LCD. And only use schematic signals when moving between pages. It does have some merit in splitting up huge IC like some LQFP144 into different function blocks. But then it should be: function block containing serial comm on the the page with serial comm, function block containing ADC on the page with analog reads etc.

Comment: As for general feedback: don't design RF products on 2 layer boards. Pre-made modules like this might not be as picky, but it's still not a good idea. Ideally don't route any traces underneath RF parts but keep ground pour there. Then connect the ground planes with vias at as many places as possible around the RF parts.

Comment: @Lundin unfortunately I don't agree with the people forming the general consensus you mention because I believe that a schematic, where possible, should all be on one sheet. I think hierarchically distributed schematics are really hard to read; especially so if you have only a PDF output with many sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka Complex boards simply don't fit on one sheet. In case you have some >1000 components with some 5-6 complex IC, then trying to cram it all into one page is a no-go. Also the worst kind of schematics all categories are those of the "follow the line and see where you end up" variety, with some 30+ lines criss-crossing each other all over the place. Those are not only impossible to read but also very error prone.

Comment: Following the line is far, far better than trying to follow an off-sheet connector to see where it ends up.

Comment: There's an airwire near U4.

Comment: @Andyaka It really isn't. RL horror story: I know an engineer who believes the same, [this](https://imagesharing.com//photo.php?s=eqh9x2dc) is a glimpse from one of their designs which went into live production. Everyone trying to troubleshoot this board end up doing it wrong. Figuring out how something on it works takes ridiculous amounts of time. And at each board spin they ended up doing silly mistakes because they couldn't easily read their own schematic. And then this wasn't even a complex board, just lots of connectors. It was bad engineering in its purest form.

Comment: @lundin sorry, I have to fundamentally disagree with you. Maybe your schematic was drawn badly in the first place i.e. it wasn't thought out correctly in the way it should be presented. The image you present is meaningless in this context.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh it was horribly drawn, but I can't share it since it's proprietary. Fact remains that because of "follow the line" I couldn't read this schematic of a PCB with approx 100 components and some 50 connector points. Whereas I have no trouble reading a schematic of a far more complex product by another designer, where we have some ~2k components including numerous regulators, MCUs, RFICs, MEMS parts, UI stuff, hundreds of connector points etc etc. The schematic design must be adapted to the complexity of the board, there's no one size fits all.

Comment: @Andyaka I do get the argument against using signals needlessly just for the sake of it though, especially between two parts on the same page. That's just needlessly confusing.

Comment: I believe there is a middle ground.  In principal and in general, I agree with @Andyaka, on one page with lines.  That said, there are plenty of situations where I break that rule-of-thumb.  For instance, a high pin-count MCU with many lines going to a connector with lots of cross-overs...net labels with signal names works best for me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Feedback on PCB-layout wanted*

1. Reserve the GND flood for the blue side
2. Minimize the length of any tracks that are not GND on the blue side
3. Where possible use the red-side flood for power supplies like 3.3 volts
4. Follow recommendations in data sheets for PCB layout

These are all obvious tracks to move (almost in their entirety) to the red-side: -

[image]

5. Try and place components all on one side of the PCB

**Reason**: minimize disruption of the GND plane to vastly improve EMI withstand and EMI generation. If that means extra vias that's OK in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just some observations:

- Your schematic is basically an accumulation of components and net labels. One can make a case for personal preference for sure, but just having a lot of labels makes it very hard to understand signal flow and the basic logic of the circuit. Arrange your components in a reasonable way and connect them with wires instead of labels.
- You should try to have an as solid as practicable GND plane on the bottom layer. Only route signals on the bottom layer if you absolutely have to. And when you have to, keep them as short as possible.
- I'm not really a fan of "multiple boards in one" trickery. Your split GND net is an obvious example: Your CAD tool will flag this as an error. Once you start ignoring/disabling design rule checks you are asking for trouble eventually.
  Also you accidentally created an inside "radius" that needs to be milled. Since that inside radius is zero, the outcome is undefined as it will depend on the milling tool size of your fabricator. Or your order might get "on hold" for clarification.
  Then you had to come up with weird net names like "SDL_2" or "BME_VDD" to keep the nets of the boards separated.
  Depending on your fabricator my guess is that a two-in-one board won't provide much cost advantage anyway. Since it appears to be a low volume project, you'll probably order the boards from a pooling service. So the boards will probably end up on the same panel anyway and you can let the fabricator worry about panelizeation.
- V-Scoring makes sense for high volume production where a whole panel is filled with multiple instances of a single design. Since you'll probably use a pooling service, v-scoring might not make much sense.